# SQL server Datediff for integer date values

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi all I am having a oracle query as follows

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(Sysdate, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd') - to_date(date_column, 'yyyymmdd') from table
```

This I migrated to SQL as follows, where I will have the date saved in SQL table as `INTEGER` format

```
DECLARE @sysDate INT = CAST (SUBSTRING(REPLACE(convert(datetime2, GETDATE(),102) ,'-',''),1,8) AS INT)
```

This is the following query

```
datediff(day,convert(datetime,convert(char(8),@sysDate)) , convert(datetime,convert(char(8), date_column)))
```

Is it the right way or is there any other better way to do this

Comment: Why are you storing the data as `int`s when SQL Server already has several perfectly functional data types (such as `date`) that have the correct semantics and functions defined for them?

Comment: I am not that much aware of the sql functions